# When does this post-incrementation happen?

Tags: java, if-statement, increment

I have this piece of Java code in front of me:

```
private static int[] generateSparseArray(int value) {
    int[] array = new int[getBound(value)];
    for (int j = 1; j < value; j++) {
        do {
            array[j++] = value;
            if ((value++ > 3 || value < 4) && (j > 0)) {
                ++j;
                break; 
            }
        } while (value < 4); 
    }
    return array; 
}

private static int getBound(int value) { /** ... */ }
```

I am not sure if this will increment "value" after checking specifically this piece of the boolean expression or if it will increment after the entire boolean expression of the if-statement.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Please avoid using images to show code in questions. Instead, put the text of the code into your question. Please [edit] it. Why ?  searchability for the next person with a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

The post-increment is done *immediately* after evaluation of `value`, not after the evaluation of the whole `if` condition.

Look at `(value++ > 3 || value < 4)` and with `value` being `3`:

- `value` is evaluated and is `3`, so the first part of the condition is `false`
- immediately afterwards `value` is incremented to `4`
- Since the first part of the OR expression was false, the second part is evaluated and not short-circuited.
- Now `value` is already `4` and the second part of the condition is also `false`

You can verify this by looking at a stripped down version.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 3;
    if((a++ > 3 || a < 4) && verify(a)) {

    }
}

static boolean verify(int a) {
    System.out.println(a);
    return true;
}
```

The method `verify` is never called and nothing is printed, because `(a++ > 3 || a < 4)` is `false` and short-circuiting takes place.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really anything to do with being in an `if` statement; it is simply expression evaluation.

The operation is spelled out explicitly in [the Java Lanaguage Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7).

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated
> before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.